# How can I implement an OAuth flow in a CXF endpoint (SOAP) in Camel (preferably Blueprint)?

Tags: oauth-2.0, apache-camel, cxf, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi

I would like to address a SOAP web service via **camel-cxf endpoint**. How can I implement an **OAuth flow**, preferably in the blueprint? Is that configurative or do I have to implement it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found nice [documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-oauth2.html#JAX-RSOAuth2-OAuth2tokensandSOAPendpoints) on this:

Basically, you have to implement interceptors and filters:
Your **blueprint.xml**

```
<bean id="tvServiceClientFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean">
    <property name="address" value="http://localhost:${http.port}/services/oauth/validate"/>
    <property name="headers">
        <map>
            <entry key="Accept" value="application/xml"/>
            <entry key="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="tvServiceClient" factory-bean="tvServiceClientFactory" factory-method="createWebClient"/>

<bean id="tokenValidator" class="org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.filters.AccessTokenValidatorClient">
    <property name="tokenValidatorClient" ref="tvServiceClient"/>
</bean>

<bean id="oauthFiler" class="org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.filters.OAuthRequestFilter">
    <property name="tokenValidator" ref="tokenValidator"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myApp" class="org.myapp.MyApp"/>

<jaxrs:server id="fromThirdPartyToMyApp" address="/thirdparty-to-myapp">
   <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
      <ref bean="myApp"/>
  </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
  <jaxrs:providers>
      <ref bean="oauthFilter"/>
  </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Comment: Yes, this is a nice documentation. The section you refer to is for protecting a resource, but I want to access a resource. So I want to implement the client side. So I think the section [Client-side support](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-oauth2.html#JAX-RSOAuth2-Client-sidesupport) is more interesting here. And now I try to create an example for SOAP and not REST. Maybe directly in a cxf:cxfEndpoint for SOAP.

Comment: Or do I have to get my Token with JAX-RS client and then use the Tokens in my SOAP Endpoint?

Comment: What i have seen yet, backend should register token if user's credentials are correct, send it to the client and then in each other request it should verify token and send reply. I think that client should send SOAP with it!s credentials and get token - each other request goes with token inside.